# How to stop gradle from downloading every time

Tags: gradle

I have installed gradle in Ubuntu 16.04. 

Here is the output for `gradle -v`

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-01-26 15:17:49 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     UNKNOWN

Groovy:       2.4.5
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on July 8 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_101 (Oracle Corporation 25.101-b13)
OS:           Linux 4.4.0-38-generic amd64
```

But even now, whenever I create a new project based on gradle v2.10, it downloads it and then builds the project. According to the tutorials, after installing it, I shouldn't need to download it again. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 9):

you will have to replace url with local path like this

```
distributionUrl = file\:///e:/android/gradle-2.10-bin.zip
```

and comment

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

in gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score 4):

I think you have two concepts mixed up:

1. A manual installation of gradle (`gradle.bat` / `gradle.sh`)
2. The [gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) (`gradlew.bat` / `gradlew.sh`)

When you mention executing `gradle -v` this has absolutely no effect on the gradle wrapper. The wrapper works independently of any manually installed gradle versions.

Since you are referencing gradle being downloaded I assume you are discussing the gradle wrapper (`gradlew`). The wrapper will first check if it has downloaded the version previously by checking the cache stored under `$GRADLE_USER_HOME` so will only ever download each version once. Subsequent `gradlew` invocations will use the previously downloaded/unzipped installation.

Comment: I have run the gradlew script once already too. Trying it the next time started the download again. Should I remove the installed gradle copy and start fresh?

Comment: Has `$GRADLE_USER_HOME` been deleted between executions? Has `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` changed? As I said, your manually installed gradle version has no effect on gradlew

Comment: I stumbled into cases where the gradle wrapper in .gradle folder deleted automatically. This usually happens when I don't open a project for more than a month. Does these wrappers follows LRU and deletes after some time?

Comment: Whenever I opens android project it starts downloading gradle files everytime. sometimes it just downloads multiple smaller files and sometimes it downloads around 130 mb file